# Multi-configuration project on CloudBees' Jenkins for FOSS

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees

Can FOSS (free) user use multi-configuration project in Jenkins at CloudBees? The FOSS (free) user has only one available executor but multi-configuration project requires at least two for:

- controller that starts each configuration
- specific configuration invoked by controller

The controller is the job (dispatcher) that invokes all configurations one by one. Please take a look at the logs of my multi-configuration project: [Simple Spring Memcached](https://ragnor.ci.cloudbees.com/job/SSM%20%28integration%20tests%29/2/). When the controller trigger first configuration it doesn't release job executor.

Is it any workaround for this?

The only way that I see to make it work is to split multi-configuration project into several single (maven) projects but I'd like to avoid it.

Comment: What is a “controller” in this context and why would one be needed to “invoke a configuration”? A general matrix project would just have some configuration axes and then Jenkins would build all the combinations, on whatever executor(s) you have at your disposal. So please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only workaround I can think of is to trigger your multi-configuration job with another job. This "do-nothing' job will provision the slave, do nothing, and then trigger the matrix build as a post-build action. The matrix job will then be able to both run the matrix parent build and all of the configuration's children.

Comment: Amazing! I don't know why but it works like a charm. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Jenkins will only run the parent matrix job as a FlyWeightTask if it can find at least one running computer. If none are found, it's scheduled as a regular build and so consumes a full executor. By pre-provisioning the slave, Jenkins will see the computer available before making the fly-weight decision. I guess that decision should be delayed somehow,or perhaps re-evaluated.